# How do I convert this sparse matrix to the normal one?

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix represented as

```
> (f <- data.frame(row=c(1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3,4,1,1,2),value=1:12))
   row value
1    1     1
2    2     2
3    3     3
4    1     4
5    2     5
6    1     6
7    2     7
8    3     8
9    4     9
10   1    10
11   1    11
12   2    12
```

Here the first column is always present (in fact, the first few are present, the rest are not).

I want to get the data into the matrix format:

```
> t(matrix(c(1,2,3,NA,4,5,NA,NA,6,7,8,9,10,NA,NA,NA,11,12,NA,NA),nrow=4,ncol=5))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3   NA
[2,]    4    5   NA   NA
[3,]    6    7    8    9
[4,]   10   NA   NA   NA
[5,]   11   12   NA   NA
```

Here is what seems to be working:

```
> library(Matrix)
> as.matrix(sparseMatrix(i = cumsum(f[[1]] == 1), j=f[[1]], x=f[[2]]))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    0
[2,]    4    5    0    0
[3,]    6    7    8    9
[4,]   10    0    0    0
[5,]   11   12    0    0
```

Except that I have to replace `0` with `NA` myself.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Nothing wrong. I only question the use of `as.matrix` and `NA`. If you are truly working with a large sparse matrix, you should stop at `sparseMatrix`.

Comment: @flodel: it's not large and it's not a matrix. I am only using `sparseMatrix` for parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do everything with `base` functions. The trick is to use indexing by a 2-col (row and col indices) matrix:

```
j <- f$row
i <- cumsum(j == 1)
x <- f$value
m <- matrix(NA, max(i), max(j))
m[cbind(i, j)] <- x
m
```

Whether it is better or not than using the `Matrix` package is subjective. Overkill in my opinion if you are not doing anything else with it. Also if your data had `0` in the f$value column, they would end up being converted as `NA` if you are not too careful.